# Problem with website indexing on Google (Wordpress + Yoast plugin)

Tags: wordpress, indexing, google-search-console, yoast

I am using Wordpress and Yoast plugin and I have problem with website indexing. I added the website to the Google search console succesfully and verify it in Wordpress dashboard. Also I added sitemaps succesfully (image below)
[image: Image of sitemap]

But my page is not indexed on the Google, it says that there is some problem with noindex pages. I will provide you more images below:
[image: Image1]
[image: Image2]
[image: Image3]
[image: Image4]

Does someone know some solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check if your Wordpress installation is [allowing Search Engines](https://www.wpbeginner.com/beginners-guide/how-to-stop-search-engines-from-crawling-a-wordpress-site/) to index your site?

Comment: It is unchecked to me, so it should be ok.